# Show some controls based on radio button choice

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing an example exam assignment, where I have to make a form that builds different shapes based on different form choices.

I have a radio button group with 3 options. Based on the selected option I have to show next set of few more options. Is the proper way of doing that is to put few `Panel` with different buttons one over another, make all hidden and show none but one when selecting a radio button from the first group or there is a more standard way?

Comment: Be careful when overlapping panel with the designer. You could inadvertently make a panel children of another panel. Better leave the panels in different position with just one at the right position. At the Form_Load event or after the InitializeComponent move the other panels exactly over the Location position of the first one

Comment: @Steve is right, this should be the answer. Having controls overlap each other is a pain in the ass for anyone reviewing the design. Create the initial panel where you want it, create the others with visibility turned off somewhere else on the form, and just hide the initial and move the subject panel to its position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a correct way to handle this scenario. 
However I don't recommend to overlap the panels with the Form Designer. 
There is a large probability that you inadvertently make a panel children of another panel.
I prefer to leave the panels in different position with just one at the right position.
At the Form_Load event or after the InitializeComponent I move the other panels exactly over the Location position of the first one

So for example

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel2.Location = panel1.Location;
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd still do:

   `panel1.Visible = false;` Just in case the Z order gets jacked up.

Comment: Well that could be left in the designer. Every panel starts with Visible = False unless you want one visible as default.

Comment: Not if he designed the panels with the designer... They are visible by default.

Comment: We are saying the same thing. Just I thought that when he says _made all the panels hidden_ he do so with the designer.

Comment: My bad, I missed that in OP's question. Gotcha